# Windows Task Scheduler, Parent and Children tasks

Tags: batch-file, scheduler

Windows Server 2019 standard

We have a situation where we need to run 25+ tasks each for multiple business units within a company. We currently have these all in the task scheduler. They look like this:

```
Task1
Task11
Task12
Task13
Task14
Task2
Task21
Task22
......
......
```

and so on until we get to Task54.

These tasks are currently duplicated for each business unit by exporting them, editing the xml files and then re-importing. PITA and a complete overload and growing like cancer.

Currently each scheduled task runs a bat file that invokes an executable. If I stop the scheduled task then the bat file stops and in turn the executable stops.

My idea instead of these 25 jobs is to have just 5 "parent" tasks in the scheduler. - Task1 to Task5. Each of these would run a bat or cmd file which in turn would look for other batch/cmd files with a certain naming pattern, so Task1 would run any bat files it finds that begin with "Task1". Each of these would run the executable in question.

Here's the million dollar question (and yes, I am setting this up to test later today). If I stop scheduled task1, how can I ensure that all its children (task11.bat - task15.bat) also stop? I know I can have one bat file run another with the /wait parameter but I need it to basically start five children and if the parent is stopped (from the task scheduler) then to also ensure that the 5 children also stop.

A few people have asked what the batch file looks like so I have added an example. A few things that should be clarified. The executable sees the "-b" flag (batch) and so runs without a window being seen.

Because the batch file currently "hangs" waiting for the executable to end, when we tell the scheduled task (the bat file) to "End" then it automatically terminates the executable as well.

The problem I am trying to address is "how can we have a 'parent' task that, when ended, also stops all its children tasks? example shown below"?.

```
REM 11.bat 
call Pro2_env.bat 
cd %PRO2SQL% 
title "%PRO2SQL% ReplProc Thread-11" 
"%PROEXE%" -ininame Pro2.ini -basekey "INI" -b -pf %REPLPF% -p %CODEDIR%\RunReplProc.p -param "Thread=11"
```

Hope this clarifies the situation. Thanks to all who have made suggestions so far. I suspect I may have to "roll my own" on this one.

Comment: Personally I suggest just one scheduld job that calls a PowerShell file that does all the stuff - works out required command lines (possibly from a config file) and takes care of  workflow and notifications